# MouseLeave LostFocus events Silverlight

Tags: events, silverlight-3.0, windows-phone-7

I'm writing a Windows phone 7 Silverlight Application. and i have to set Visibility of my Stackpanel to Collapsed when mouse leaves this control. But this event occurs even if i simply click on my control without mouse movings. Lost focus event doesn't work too.
How to achieve my goal?
Thx in advance!

Answer (score 3):

LostFocus is only triggered when a user taps on another control, as mentioned there are no hover events as the mouse metaphor does not work here as this is a touch-based environment - the best way to deal with control behaviour is to imagine using your finger to interact with the control - this may allow to design a behaviour which works the way you want, then see how this would work practically, a touch on the screen starts a click so there is no mousemove without a mousedown too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a "mouse hover" effect, then you might need to rethink how the user interacts with your application as MouseMove events are fired only while the user has a finger down on the screen.